# Threaded Perl with each thread in a new xterm

Tags: multithreading, perl, xterm

I'm creating a threaded program where not all threads are spawned at the beginning. Some have to wait for 1 or more threads to complete first. This would not be a problem, except I would like to keep the `xterm`s open to read through the output. In some cases, piping to a file does not work as there is some fancy stuff going on with the terminal output where it overwrites itself.

I have been using
`my $xt_hold = "xterm -sl 5000 -geometry 350x50+0+100 -iconic -hold -e $cmd"; system($xt_hold);` to create the `xterm` but this does not allow me to join the thread when it is finished. Is there another way I can keep the xterm open and know when/join the thread when it is finished?

If there is a better solution using GNU `screen` then I would probably be interested in that, but my primary choice would be `xterm` just because I am more familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry, might mis-understand. When you say `my $xt_hold = "xterm -sl 5000 ... -e $cmd"` do you mean `my $xt_hold = \`xterm -sl 5000 ...\``? Are you using backticks to spawn an xterm shell or are you just putting a string in `$xt_hold`?

Comment: Calling it with `system`, so `xt_hold` is only a string. The question is simplified compared to actual code. Updated question with your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to answer this, I realized something. The characters that were showing up in the text files were control characters for color and I guess there are also delete/backspace ones. These can only be interpreted by terminals, so I can just view the logfiles in the original terminal with `less -r`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use another approach: **queue**.

Using `Thread::Queue` you can tell each *working threads* to place results into the queue. Another thread (**created for output**) will read from the queue and output it to the terminal (or file, or DB etc.).